# resolve error for Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open server excel as a workbook in client machine but i am not able to open it, but with same code it is working perfectly on local machine.

My c# code is as under

```cs
string physicalFileName1 = "";

hfDrive.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Patientuplao"].ToString();

string filename = txtfile1.Text;
physicalFileName1 = hfDrive.Value + "\\" + filename + "\\PatientChart.xls";
if (txtfile1.Text != "")
{
    try
    {
        physicalFileName1 = hfDrive.Value + "\\" + filename + "\\PatientChart.xls";
        var excelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelapp.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks wbook = excelapp.Workbooks;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = wbook.Open(physicalFileName1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtMessage.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

after this implementation i got this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: By Your Code - In your local machine it will work - because Client & Server are same.You are trying to launch Excel application in Server using Interop.  (May be Interop Excel is not available in Server). What you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the user that is running the website (you are using asp.net) doesn't have the permission on the desired workbook. Try to change the permissions on the workbook on the server and add the user that is running the website.

Comment: i already set it with  my user but still haven't change anything.

Comment: You can download the file locally and open it with Excel. If you change something, you can also upload it.